# Magento : Show same product as separate in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, qty

I have products with different custom options. When a same product with same custom options is added to cart twice, it appears in the cart as `2 X qty`
Please refer the image 
[image]

I want to display it as separate product. Please refer the below image.

[image]

How can I do it. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

Copy the file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php`

Set the return as `false` in function `representProduct()`

Answer (score 0):

Magento shows product with different options separately. You need to add an additional option programmatically using observer.

Go through below link to do the same.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1efPznQSVTrT1HAD1xQvCPC-Tgvr8jYok4X7ZEJhm9jE/edit#slide=id.gd03b59c1_026